# JavaScript if statements not functioning

Tags: javascript

I'm sure there is a perfectly logical explanation to why this isn't working the way I want it to but I am new to JavaScript so would love some help. Is there any reason you would know as to why it prints out yes even when I want it to print out no.
Thanks in advance

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var username = prompt("What is your VC?");
    if (username = "wow") {
        greeting = document.write("yes");
    } else {
        document.write("no");
    }  
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `=` operator is used for assignment, for checking the value you can use `===`. 
So, change the if as follows:

```
if (username === "wow")
```

Working code is given below:

```js
var username = prompt("What is your VC?");
if (username === "wow") { 
    greeting = document.write("yes"); 
} else 
{ 
    document.write("no"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. One `=` is assignment. Two `==` tests equality. And three `===` tests [strict equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators).

```js
var username = prompt("What is your VC?");
if (username === "wow") {
  document.write("yes");
} else {
  document.write("no");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say:

```
a = b
```

You're saying "set a to the value in b."

If you out that in an if statement's expression, it assigns b to a and thrn checks if a's new value is "truthy."

If you want to ask "is a equal to b," you have to say:

```
a == b
```

I know that there is a difference between == and ===, but I am not a JavaScript master, so I cannot tell you what the difference is!

Comment: `===` compares type. `true == "true"`, but `true !== "true"`